# How can I remove the slide transition and add more pages under single screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**I am not able to remove the transition animation during screen change . And also I want add more screens inside all the existing screens and navigate between those screens with the help of buttons.**

*I am very new to kivy and kivymd , your help will be just be electrifying to me.*
**Thank You Very Much In Advance.**

***Python Code (main.py):***

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder


class main_app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('gu.kv')


main_app().run()
```

***KV File (gu.kv)***

```
NavigationLayout:
    # Screens of different pages
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        name: 'screen_manager'

        # search_items_screen
        Screen:
            id: search_items_screen
            name: 'search_items_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'search_items_screen'

        # daily_book_screen
        Screen:
            id: daily_book_screen
            name: 'daily_book_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'daily_book_screen'

        # udhar_book_screen
        Screen:
            id: udhar_book_screen
            name: 'udhar_book_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'udhar_book_screen'

        # entry_book_screen
        Screen:
            id: entry_book_screen
            name: 'entry_book_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'entry_book_screen'

        # trending_screen
        Screen:
            id: trending_screen
            name: 'trending_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'trending_screen'

        # statistics_screen
        Screen:
            id: statistics_screen
            name: 'statistics_screen'
            # Menu_toggle button
            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'menu'
                pos_hint: {'center_x':.03, 'center_y':.945}
                on_release: navigation_drawer.set_state("open")
            MDLabel:
                text: 'statistics_screen'



    # Navigation Drawer
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: navigation_drawer
        name: 'navigation_drawer'
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Search Items'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'search_items_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Daily Book'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'daily_book_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Udhar Book'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'udhar_book_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Entry Book'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'entry_book_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Trending'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'trending_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: 'Statistics'
                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current= 'statistics_screen'
                        navigation_drawer.set_state("close")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the default `SlideTransition` by using `NoTransition` in your `kv`:

```
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
NavigationLayout:
    # Screens of different pages
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        name: 'screen_manager'
        transition: NoTransition()
```

As for more screens, you can add another `ScreenManager` inside a `Screen` and use that inner `ScreenManager` to switch among the children of that inner `ScreenManager`.